# Why does my custom tab bar get pushed up everytime the on screen keyboard pops up?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've made a custom tab bar and I'm trying to add a search bar on one of my views. For some reason half of the tab gets pushed up when the onscreen keyboard appears. Ive tried "  .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)" literally everywhere and the only thing that happens is my icons for the tab disappear but the top of the tab still stays there. I've been trying to fix it for the last 24 hours but I'm getting nowhere, can somebody please help me with this. Thanks!

Code for Custom Tab Bar:

```
import SwiftUI

enum Tabs: Int {
    case home = 0
    case hot = 1
    case favourites = 2
    case settings = 3
}



struct TabBar: View {
    
    @Binding  var selectedTab : Tabs
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack (alignment: .center){
            
            
            Button {
                //switch to home
                selectedTab = .home
            } label: {
                
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    
                    if selectedTab == .home {
                        
                        Rectangle()
                           // .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width/2, height: 5)
                            .padding(.leading, geo.size.width/4)
                        
                        
                    }
                    VStack (alignment: .center){
                        
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                           // .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                            .padding(.top, 40.0)
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                   // .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                   
                    
                }
                //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                .offset(y: -35)
                //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
            }
           // .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .tint(Color.black)
            
            
            
            
            Button {
                //Switch views
                selectedTab = .hot
            } label: {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    
                    if selectedTab == .hot {
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width/2, height: 5)
                            .padding(.leading, geo.size.width/4)
                        
                        
                    }
                    VStack (alignment: .center){
                        Image(systemName: "flame")
                            //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                            .padding(.top, 40.0)
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                    
                    
                    
                }
               //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                .offset(y: -35)
                
            }
           //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .tint(Color.black)
            
            
            Button {
                //Switch views
                selectedTab = .favourites
            } label: {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    
                    if selectedTab == .favourites {
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width/2, height: 5)
                            .padding(.leading, geo.size.width/4)
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .center){
                        Image(systemName: "star")
                            //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                            .padding(.top, 40.0)
                        
                        
                        
                    }//.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                   
                    
                    
                }
                //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                .offset(y: -35)
                
            }
            //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .tint(Color.black)
            
            
            
            Button {
                //Switch views
                selectedTab = .settings
            } label: {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    
                    if selectedTab == .settings {
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width/2, height: 5)
                            .padding(.leading, geo.size.width/4)
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .center){
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                            //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                            .padding(.top, 40.0)
                        
                        
                        
                    }//.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                   
                    
                    
                    
                }
                //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                .offset(y: -35)
               
            }
            //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .tint(Color.black)
            
            
        }
        //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .all)
        .frame(height: 20)

        
        
        
    }
}

struct TabBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBar(selectedTab: .constant(.home))
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    }
}
```

ignoresSafeArea is commented in all the places I tried to put it.

Here is also the code for the search bar, maybe I need to input ignoreSafeArea somewhere here?

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBarView: View {
    
    @StateObject var im = SearchBarContents()
    

    //@State var selectedTabs: SearchB = .search
    @State private var query = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        

        NavigationView {
            
            
            List {
                
                ForEach(im.filteredData) { item in
                    HStack{
                        NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: item))
                        {
                            
                            SBarView(item: item)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
            
           
            .searchable(text: $query,
                        placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always),
                        prompt: "Find an Item") {
                
            }
                        .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                            im.search(with: query)
                        }
                        .onChange(of: query) { newQuery in
                            im.search(with: newQuery)
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            im.search()
                        }
            
        }        
        
    }
}

struct SearchBarView_previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchBarView()
    }
}
```

If there is anything missing please let me know.

Imgur link to see exactly what I mean

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y46bK.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K31BB.jpg (after I add ignoresafearea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you have set up your project.  If you have a RootView which is controlling the View to be displayed based on the selection of your Tab Bar and is also the location in the project that you would add the Custom Tab Bar, then on that root View add the modifier `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)`

For example:

```
enum Tabs: Int {
    case home = 0
    case hot = 1
    case favourites = 2
    case settings = 3
}

struct RootView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = Tabs.home
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch selectedTab {
            case .home:
                HomeView()
            case .hot:
                HotView()
            case .favourites:
                FavouritesView()
            case .settings:
                SettingsView()
            }

            Spacer()

            CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    }
}
```